# Sending a metric using VisualStudio AppCenter in Android is not registered

Tags: kotlin, service, visual-studio-app-center

I'm building an application, one of the things we would like to do is to check how many of our users don't order any items (they open the application and close it). I tried 2 ways to achieve this:

1. I have created a service and override onTaskRemoved, the service is working correctly and it will prompt me a log when it's in the onTaskRemoved method, unfortunately I can't see this new metric in the AppCenter for some reason. The metric JUST_A_TEST_IGNORE is working and I can see it in the website.
2. I tried also to send this metric in the onDestroy of an activity but with the same results (it does not send anything).

Other metrics that I already placed in the application are working without any problem.

This is the of my service:

```
class RemoveTaskService : Service() {

private var isLead : String? = null

companion object{
    const val IS_LEAD_KEY = "IS_LEAD_KEY"
}

override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? { return null }


override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {

    isLead = if(intent !=null && intent.hasExtra(IS_LEAD_KEY)) intent.getStringExtra(IS_LEAD_KEY) else "0"
    val properties = HashMap<String, String>()
    properties["USER_TYPE"] = if (isLead == "0") "Invited User" else "Regular User"
    Analytics.trackEvent("JUST_A_TEST_IGNORE", properties)

    return START_NOT_STICKY
}

override fun onTaskRemoved(rootIntent: Intent?) {
   // super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent)
     val get : Boolean = Analytics.isEnabled().get()
    val done : Boolean = Analytics.isEnabled().isDone
    Log.d("testapp","get=$get done=$done")
    val properties = HashMap<String, String>()
    properties["USER_TYPE"] = if (isLead == "0") "Invited User" else "Regular User"
    Analytics.trackEvent("ORDER_NOT_COMPLETED", properties)
}
```

}

The output of the log is:

```
D/testapp: get=true done=false
```

I also tried with or without

```
super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent)
```

but without any luck

**--Edit--**

After I followed Ivan suggestion and put

```
AppCenter.setLogLevel(Log.VERBOSE)
```

in my code, I noticed the following log:

```
D/AppCenter: Storing a log to the Persistence database for log type event with flags=1
```

Is there a way to send the log instead of storing it?

Comment: Check the things from this troubleshooting guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/troubleshooting/android#analytics-data-doesnt-show-up-in-the-portal

If it's still the case, open support ticket (open the help menu in the upper right corner of the App Center portal: ? > Contact support) and attach SDK verbose logs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I think the log is stored on the device instead of sending it to the backend, is there a way to send it?

Comment: yes, device log is not shared via network
You can share it manually with the support.

BTW logs are always stored before sending (to handle network erros, application crashes etc)